# Jq-Plot x-Axis Spacing

Tags: jqplot

I am having an issue using a line chart getting the calculated labels in the x-axis to space properly.  If I want to have 5 data points with a few missing (e.g. [1,50.1],[2,49.2],[5,20.4],[6,17],[7,23.3]), the x-axis will show 1 then 2 then a space where 3 and 4 should have been then 5, 6, and 7.  What I would like is to have the 5th data point beside the 2nd data point (in the position where the 3rd data point would ideally be).  Basically I am trying to hide a data point yet keep the x-axis value in the grid.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [[[1,50],[2,49],[5,20],[6,17],[7,23]]], {
        title: 'Plot',
        axesDefaults: {
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                label: "X Axis",
                pad: 0,
                ticks:[1,2,5,6,7] //you can create this dynamically
            },
            yaxis: {
                label: "Y Axis"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var producciones = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) { producciones.push(new Number(i),new Number(i)) }
    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [producciones], {
        title: 'Plot',
        axesDefaults: {
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                label: "X Axis",
                pad: 0,
                numberTicks: 100
            },
            yaxis: {
                label: "Y Axis"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have it working now.  I had to make the Ticks a 2 dimensional array such as [[0,1],[1,2],[2,5], [3,6],[4,7]] and it worked.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: This works well for small data sets, but for large data sets, the x-axis in not readable.  Is there a way to define many ticks (say 2,000) yet use the autoScale or a similar feature?  I have tried setting NumberTicks and TickInterval and they do not seem to work as expected.

Comment: I added a new example. Maybe It helps you. I created a graph with 2000 points and the x-axis is readable.